# Deploy dacpac: Could not deploy package. Warning SQL72012

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, dacpac

I'm having this issue when I run the dacpac in the database

**Log:**

> Deploy dacpac: Could not deploy package. Warning SQL72012: The object
> [data_0] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though
> you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the
> target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Warning SQL72012: The object [log] exists in the target, but it will
> not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements
> for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the
> source' check box. Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data
> Provider: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the
> keyword 'values'. Error SQL72045: Script execution error.

The executed
SQL SCRIPT:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Pais] ON 
GO 
insert into dbo.pais  ([idPais], [nome], [idImportado], [bitativo]) 
select a.[idPais],  a.[nome],  a.[idImportado],  a.[bitativo] from ( values
  (1, N'Brasil', NULL, 0)
, (2, N'USA', NULL, 0)
, (3, N'France', NULL, 0)
, (4, N'Germany', NULL, 0)
, (1267, N'Andorra', N'AD', 1)
, (1268, N'United Arab Emirates', N'AE', 1)
, (1269, N'Afghanistan', N'AF', 1)
, (1270, N'Antigua and Barbuda', N'AG', 1)
, (1271, N'Anguilla', N'AI', 1)
, (1272, N'Albania', N'AL', 1)
, (1273, N'Armenia', N'AM', 1)
, (1274, N'Netherlands Antilles', N'AN', 1)
,(1275, N'Angola', N'AO', 1)
,(1276, N'Antarctica', N'AQ', 1)
,(1277, N'Argentina', N'AR', 1)
,(1278, N'American Samoa', N'AS', 1)
,(1279, N'Austria', N'AT', 1)
,(1280, N'Australia', N'AU', 1)
,(1281, N'Aruba', N'AW', 1)
,(1282, N'Aland Islands', N'AX', 1)
,(1283, N'Azerbaijan', N'AZ', 1)
,(1284, N'Bosnia and Herzegovina', N'BA', 1)
,(1285, N'Barbados', N'BB', 1)
,(1286, N'Bangladesh', N'BD', 1)
,(1287, N'Belgium', N'BE', 1)
,(1288, N'Burkina Faso', N'BF', 1)
,(1289, N'Bulgaria', N'BG', 1)
,(1290, N'Bahrain', N'BH', 1)
,(1291, N'Burundi', N'BI', 1)
,(1292, N'Benin', N'BJ', 1)
,(1293, N'Saint Barthélemy', N'BL', 1) 
,(1294, N'Bermuda', N'BM', 1) 
,(1295, N'Brunei', N'BN', 1) 
,(1296, N'Bolivia', N'BO', 1) 
,(1297, N'Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba ', N'BQ', 1) 
,(1298, N'Brazil', N'BR', 1) 
,(1299, N'Bahamas', N'BS', 1) 
,(1300, N'Bhutan', N'BT', 1) 
,(1301, N'Bouvet Island', N'BV', 1) 
,(1302, N'Botswana', N'BW', 1) 
,(1303, N'Belarus', N'BY', 1) 
,(1304, N'Belize', N'BZ', 1) 
,(1305, N'Canada', N'CA', 1) 
,(1306, N'Cocos Islands', N'CC', 1) 
,(1307, N'Democratic Republic of the Congo', N'CD', 1) 
,(1308, N'Central African Republic', N'CF', 1) 
,(1309, N'Republic of the Congo', N'CG', 1) 
,(1310, N'Switzerland', N'CH', 1) 
,(1311, N'Ivory Coast', N'CI', 1) 
,(1312, N'Cook Islands', N'CK', 1) 
,(1313, N'Chile', N'CL', 1) 
,(1314, N'Cameroon', N'CM', 1) 
,(1315, N'China', N'CN', 1) 
,(1316, N'Colombia', N'CO', 1)
,(1317, N'Costa Rica', N'CR', 1)
,(1318, N'Serbia and Montenegro', N'CS', 1)
,(1319, N'Cuba', N'CU', 1)
,(1320, N'Cape Verde', N'CV', 1)
,(1321, N'Curaçao', N'CW', 1)
,(1322, N'Christmas Island', N'CX', 1)
,(1323, N'Cyprus', N'CY', 1)
,(1324, N'Czech Republic', N'CZ', 1)
,(1325, N'Germany', N'DE', 1)
,(1326, N'Djibouti', N'DJ', 1)
,(1327, N'Denmark', N'DK', 1)
,(1328, N'Dominica', N'DM', 1)
,(1329, N'Dominican Republic', N'DO', 1)
,(1330, N'Algeria', N'DZ', 1)
,(1331, N'Ecuador', N'EC', 1)
,(1332, N'Estonia', N'EE', 1)
,(1333, N'Egypt', N'EG', 1)
,(1334, N'Western Sahara', N'EH', 1)
,(1335, N'Eritrea', N'ER', 1)
,(1336, N'Spain', N'ES', 1)
,(1337, N'Ethiopia', N'ET', 1)
,(1338, N'Finland', N'FI', 1) 
,(1339, N'Fiji', N'FJ', 1) 
,(1340, N'Falkland Islands', N'FK', 1)
,(1341, N'Micronesia', N'FM', 1)
,(1342, N'Faroe Islands', N'FO', 1)
,(1343, N'France', N'FR', 1)
,(1344, N'Gabon', N'GA', 1)
,(1345, N'United Kingdom', N'GB', 1)
,(1346, N'Grenada', N'GD', 1)
,(1347, N'Georgia', N'GE', 1)
,(1348, N'French Guiana', N'GF', 1)
,(1349, N'Guernsey', N'GG', 1)
,(1350, N'Ghana', N'GH', 1)
,(1351, N'Gibraltar', N'GI', 1)
,(1352, N'Greenland', N'GL', 1)
,(1353, N'Gambia', N'GM', 1)
,(1354, N'Guinea', N'GN', 1)
,(1355, N'Guadeloupe', N'GP', 1)
,(1356, N'Equatorial Guinea', N'GQ', 1)
,(1357, N'Greece', N'GR', 1)
,(1358, N'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', N'GS', 1)
,(1359, N'Guatemala', N'GT', 1) 
,(1360, N'Guam', N'GU', 1) 
,(1361, N'Guinea-Bissau', N'GW', 1) 
,(1362, N'Guyana', N'GY', 1) 
,(1363, N'Hong Kong', N'HK', 1) 
,(1364, N'Heard Island and McDonald Islands', N'HM', 1) 
,(1365, N'Honduras', N'HN', 1) 
,(1366, N'Croatia', N'HR', 1) 
,(1367, N'Haiti', N'HT', 1) 
,(1368, N'Hungary', N'HU', 1) 
,(1369, N'Indonesia', N'ID', 1) 
,(1370, N'Ireland', N'IE', 1) 
,(1371, N'Israel', N'IL', 1) 
,(1372, N'Isle of Man', N'IM', 1) 
,(1373, N'India', N'IN', 1) 
,(1374, N'British Indian Ocean Territory', N'IO', 1) 
,(1375, N'Iraq', N'IQ', 1) 
,(1376, N'Iran', N'IR', 1) 
,(1377, N'Iceland', N'IS', 1) 
,(1378, N'Italy', N'IT', 1) 
,(1379, N'Jersey', N'JE', 1) 
,(1380, N'Jamaica', N'JM', 1) 
,(1381, N'Jordan', N'JO', 1) 
,(1382, N'Japan', N'JP', 1)
 
,(1383, N'Kenya', N'KE', 1)
 
,(1384, N'Kyrgyzstan', N'KG', 1)
 
,(1385, N'Cambodia', N'KH', 1)
 
,(1386, N'Kiribati', N'KI', 1)
 
,(1387, N'Comoros', N'KM', 1)
 
,(1388, N'Saint Kitts and Nevis', N'KN', 1)
 
,(1389, N'North Korea', N'KP', 1)
 
,(1390, N'South Korea', N'KR', 1)
 
,(1391, N'Kuwait', N'KW', 1)
 
,(1392, N'Cayman Islands', N'KY', 1)
 
,(1393, N'Kazakhstan', N'KZ', 1)
 
,(1394, N'Laos', N'LA', 1)
 
,(1395, N'Lebanon', N'LB', 1)
 
,(1396, N'Saint Lucia', N'LC', 1)
 
,(1397, N'Liechtenstein', N'LI', 1)
 
,(1398, N'Sri Lanka', N'LK', 1)
 
,(1399, N'Liberia', N'LR', 1)
 
,(1400, N'Lesotho', N'LS', 1)
 
,(1401, N'Lithuania', N'LT', 1)
 
,(1402, N'Luxembourg', N'LU', 1)
 
,(1403, N'Latvia', N'LV', 1)
 
,(1404, N'Libya', N'LY', 1)
 
,(1405, N'Morocco', N'MA', 1)
 
,(1406, N'Monaco', N'MC', 1)
 
,(1407, N'Moldova', N'MD', 1)
 
,(1408, N'Montenegro', N'ME', 1)
 
,(1409, N'Saint Martin', N'MF', 1)
 
,(1410, N'Madagascar', N'MG', 1)
 
,(1411, N'Marshall Islands', N'MH', 1)
 
,(1412, N'Macedonia', N'MK', 1)
 
,(1413, N'Mali', N'ML', 1)
 
,(1414, N'Myanmar', N'MM', 1)
 
,(1415, N'Mongolia', N'MN', 1)
 
,(1416, N'Macao', N'MO', 1)
 
,(1417, N'Northern Mariana Islands', N'MP', 1)
 
,(1418, N'Martinique', N'MQ', 1)
 
,(1419, N'Mauritania', N'MR', 1)
 
,(1420, N'Montserrat', N'MS', 1)
 
,(1421, N'Malta', N'MT', 1)
 
,(1422, N'Mauritius', N'MU', 1)
 
,(1423, N'Maldives', N'MV', 1)
 
,(1424, N'Malawi', N'MW', 1)
 
,(1425, N'Mexico', N'MX', 1)
 
,(1426, N'Malaysia', N'MY', 1)
 
,(1427, N'Mozambique', N'MZ', 1)
 
,(1428, N'Namibia', N'NA', 1)
 
,(1429, N'New Caledonia', N'NC', 1)
 
,(1430, N'Niger', N'NE', 1)
 
,(1431, N'Norfolk Island', N'NF', 1)
 
,(1432, N'Nigeria', N'NG', 1)
 
,(1433, N'Nicaragua', N'NI', 1)
 
,(1434, N'Netherlands', N'NL', 1)
 
,(1435, N'Norway', N'NO', 1)
 
,(1436, N'Nepal', N'NP', 1)
 
,(1437, N'Nauru', N'NR', 1)
 
,(1438, N'Niue', N'NU', 1)
 
,(1439, N'New Zealand', N'NZ', 1)
 
,(1440, N'Oman', N'OM', 1)
 
,(1441, N'Panama', N'PA', 1)
 
,(1442, N'Peru', N'PE', 1)
 
,(1443, N'French Polynesia', N'PF', 1)
 
,(1444, N'Papua New Guinea', N'PG', 1)
,(1445, N'Philippines', N'PH', 1)
,(1446, N'Pakistan', N'PK', 1)
,(1447, N'Poland', N'PL', 1)
,(1448, N'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', N'PM', 1)
,(1449, N'Pitcairn', N'PN', 1)
,(1450, N'Puerto Rico', N'PR', 1)
,(1451, N'Palestinian Territory', N'PS', 1)
,(1452, N'Portugal', N'PT', 1)
,(1453, N'Palau', N'PW', 1)
,(1454, N'Paraguay', N'PY', 1)
,(1455, N'Qatar', N'QA', 1)
,(1456, N'Reunion', N'RE', 1)
,(1457, N'Romania', N'RO', 1)
,(1458, N'Serbia', N'RS', 1)
,(1459, N'Russia', N'RU', 1)
,(1460, N'Rwanda', N'RW', 1)
,(1461, N'Saudi Arabia', N'SA', 1)
,(1462, N'Solomon Islands', N'SB', 1)
,(1463, N'Seychelles', N'SC', 1)
,(1464, N'Sudan', N'SD', 1)
,(1465, N'Sweden', N'SE', 1)
,(1466, N'Singapore', N'SG', 1)
,(1467, N'Saint Helena', N'SH', 1)
,(1468, N'Slovenia', N'SI', 1)
,(1469, N'Svalbard and Jan Mayen', N'SJ', 1)
,(1470, N'Slovakia', N'SK', 1)
,(1471, N'Sierra Leone', N'SL', 1)
,(1472, N'San Marino', N'SM', 1)
,(1473, N'Senegal', N'SN', 1)
,(1474, N'Somalia', N'SO', 1)
,(1475, N'Suriname', N'SR', 1)
,(1476, N'South Sudan', N'SS', 1)
,(1477, N'Sao Tome and Principe', N'ST', 1)
,(1478, N'El Salvador', N'SV', 1)
,(1479, N'Sint Maarten', N'SX', 1)
,(1480, N'Syria', N'SY', 1)
,(1481, N'Swaziland', N'SZ', 1)
,(1482, N'Turks and Caicos Islands', N'TC', 1)
,(1483, N'Chad', N'TD', 1)
,(1484, N'French Southern Territories', N'TF', 1)
,(1485, N'Togo', N'TG', 1)
,(1486, N'Thailand', N'TH', 1)
,(1487, N'Tajikistan', N'TJ', 1)
,(1488, N'Tokelau', N'TK', 1)
,(1489, N'East Timor', N'TL', 1)
,(1490, N'Turkmenistan', N'TM', 1)
,(1491, N'Tunisia', N'TN', 1)
,(1492, N'Tonga', N'TO', 1)
,(1493, N'Turkey', N'TR', 1)
,(1494, N'Trinidad and Tobago', N'TT', 1)
,(1495, N'Tuvalu', N'TV', 1)
,(1496, N'Taiwan', N'TW', 1)
,(1497, N'Tanzania', N'TZ', 1)
,(1498, N'Ukraine', N'UA', 1)
,(1499, N'Uganda', N'UG', 1)
,(1500, N'United States Minor Outlying Islands', N'UM', 1)
,(1501, N'United States', N'US', 1)
,(1502, N'Uruguay', N'UY', 1)
,(1503, N'Uzbekistan', N'UZ', 1)
,(1504, N'Vatican', N'VA', 1)
,(1505, N'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', N'VC', 1)
,(1506, N'Venezuela', N'VE', 1)
,(1507, N'British Virgin Islands', N'VG', 1)
,(1508, N'U.S. Virgin Islands', N'VI', 1)
,(1509, N'Vietnam', N'VN', 1)
,(1510, N'Vanuatu', N'VU', 1)
,(1511, N'Wallis and Futuna', N'WF', 1)
,(1512, N'Samoa', N'WS', 1)
,(1513, N'Kosovo', N'XK', 1)
,(1514, N'Yemen', N'YE', 1)
,(1515, N'Mayotte', N'YT', 1)
,(1516, N'South Africa', N'ZA', 1)
,(1517, N'Zambia', N'ZM', 1)
,(1518, N'Zimbabwe', N'ZW', 1)
  )a([idPais], [nome], [idImportado], [bitativo])   
left join dbo.Pais u on a.idPais=u.idPais
where u.idPais is null
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS

1. Right-Click on the server instance, select Properties
2. Select Advanced page, set under Containment the property value to True
3. Proceed to restore the database backup.

[image]